# Override SQL Server Connection String in Legacy Application

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, legacy

I have a legacy application that has configuration parameters for SQL Server name, database, user-name and password. Presumable it then constructs its own connection string.

Is there any way to override this? I'd like to force integrated authentication (ignore supplied credentials) and enable encryption.

I know about [Aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx), but these seem to only allow changes to server address - more about hard coded server/database, but not other values.

Comment: just a suggestion add the SQL Authentication based on application  to SQL Server ?

Comment: You'd have to contact the vendor of the application as it is what builds the connection string.

Comment: Sound like a catch 22 problem... You don't want to change the client, however in order to change authentication method, the client need to change it's connection string... I guess hypothetically you could write a service that hi-jacks the connection to the db from the client and modifies it before it tries to connect, then sends the handle back to the client.

Comment: What technology was this legacy application written in?

Comment: from the strings it looks like embarcadero / delphi, but I see a JRE and jar files floating around too.